# Hand movements when lighting shabbat candles

Tags: minhag, shabbat, sources-mekorot, candle-lighting

When women light shabbat candles I often see them making hand gestures. These look like two or perhaps three circles around in the air. What is the source for this practice? Is it a law or custom? Is the candle lighting kosher without the gestures?

Comment: I recall something about bringing the light closer so the hand circles sort of beckon the light towards the face. But that might just have been something a Pre-K teacher told my kids many years ago.

Comment: @Dan, even if it were from a pre-K teacher, it may be based on deeper concepts recorded in traditional sources.

Comment: @Dan, I learned something similar (though not from a pre-K teacher).  I learned it as a custom of gathering the light, and that the motion is usually made three times.  This is between lighting and blessing, and your eyes are closed at the time.

Comment: tinok, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for your interesting questions. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. Please consider [registering](http://mi.yodeya.com/users/login) your [account](http://mi.yodeya.com/users/1542/tinok-shnishbah), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Note: I read in Rabbi Reisman's book  Pathways of the Prophets (http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422608937.html) that he looked into it and couldn't find any source or reason for it.

Answer (score 4):

The principles are:

1) Tradition has it that women accept Shabbos when they say the blessing on the candles.

2) Blessings on mitzvos should be done before the mitzvo is performed.

See [Kitzur Shulchan Oruch 75(4)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9221&st=&pgnum=122).

Because of (1), once the woman has said the blessing, it becomes Shabbos and she can no longer light the candles.

So what the women do is

- to light the candles with a match.
- blot out the light from entering their eyes.
- then say the blessing.

  (Answer 1)
- then with the hand movements they (so to speak) cause the light to
  enter their eyes.

This has always been my understanding.

(Answer 2)

But see the [Chabad.org article](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/110394/jewish/How.htm#footnote4a110394) procedure where the hand movements "usher in a special guest, the Shabbat Queen." After the third hand movement, the woman covers her eyes with her hands and recites the blessing.

I would like to know if there is any support for my first understanding.

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: I think the first part actually answers a different question (why do women cover their eyes after lighting). I'm not familiar with the chabad source (ner shabbat ch. 13). but perhaps there is more information there as to why that motion and why 3 times etc.

Comment: Yes @DoubleAA you're right - two answers and one question. The question is bottul berov. ;-)

Comment: @tinokshnishbah Yes. The handmovements in answer 1 are connected with the question as to why women cover their eyes after lighting.

Comment: Note this Chabad article http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/674406/jewish/Why-Do-Women-Wave-Their-Hands-over-the-Shabbat-Candles.htm (since you're citing their website) says there's no source for this minhag in traditional sources